# Create folder in a mapped network drive using Java

Tags: java, java-io, unc, network-drive

I'm trying to create a folder to a mapped network drive Z: using Java

Unfortunately the file is not getting created.  This is what I'm doing:

```
File file = new File("Z:/file1");
file.mkdir();
```

This code works when not using mapped network drive.  This is on Windows environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have permissions to create this directory. Try creating the directory in explorer.

Comment: Is this code running as you rather than a service?

Comment: This java code is under a web application running under Tomcat 5.5

Comment: And I can create folders through Windows Explorer.

Comment: Back to Peter Lawrey's question - is the web application running as a Windows Service? Or did you manually start Tomcat using a .bat file?

Comment: Ok yes Tomcat is running under a Windows Service.  I just took that same piece of code running under Tomcat and created a small test JAR that would create the folder on mapped drive and it worked.  I guess is privileges issues that Tomcat has.

Comment: Everything works if I start Tomcat through command prompt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I figured this out.  Tomcat is running under Windows 2003 Server. According to what I found is that when Tomcat is started under the Windows Services, for some reason it doesn't have access to the mapped network drive.
Using UNC paths worked for me.

```
File myFile = new File("\\\\server\\shared\\input");
myFile.mkdir();
```

I was able to create a folder on the mapped network drive on that server.